# Convert MTOM attachment to binary

Tags: xml, soap, binary, base64, mtom

I would like your advise regarding this problem :

I want to convert an MTOM attachment in a SOAP WS Response to a binay base64.

Exemple :

I have this payload :

```
<ns2:Response xmlns:ns2="http://xxxxx.com" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<return>
    <messages>
        <id>0</id>
        <messageContent>Dummy text</messageContent>
        <type>INFOS</type>
    </messages>
    <LabelResponse>
        <label>
            <xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:f6212d3d-7e86-4799-b227-1003bd7d0221-81412@cxf.apache.org"/>
        </label>
    </LabelResponse>
</return>
```

And I want to obtain this :

```
 <ns2:Response xmlns:ns2="http://xxxxx.com" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<return>
    <messages>
        <id>0</id>
        <messageContent>Dummy text</messageContent>
        <type>INFOS</type>
    </messages>
    <LabelResponse>
        <label>.....XXXxXxxXXxxxx .... [Binary Base64]</label>
    </LabelResponse>
</return>
```

How could I do that ? I precise that, for a particular reason, the language I can use are XSL Transformation, Javascript and Groovy. Is there a way to do that by using one of those 3 ?

Thanks in advance !